# Qt Client - LabVIEW server

Tags: qt, labview

I am trying to connect a Qt client to a LabVIEW server (acquiring analog signals). Can this be done with data sockets ?

Answer (score 2):

[Datasockets](http://zone.ni.com/devzone/cda/tut/p/id/3224) is an NI technology. It would depend if you can find a Datasocket library that you can call from Qt. I am not well-versed in Qt, but if it possible to call a C++ dll, then this is definitely available with Measurement Studio.

An simpler solution may be just to use TCP/IP which both LabVIEW(for sure) and Qt (presumably) support.

If you need further help, post more details about your app here, or on NI's forums.

Cheers!